# Qual a diferença entre .save() e .update() no Django?

Tags: django

Estou com dificuldades de entender a diferença entre eles, pois percebi que estava usando o método .save() para alterar os meus valores, porém reparei que existe o .update().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método `save` salva as alterações em um único objeto do modelo (ou seja, uma única linha do BD), enquanto o `update` pode alterar vários objetos ao mesmo tempo. As diferenças são as seguintes:

1. `objeto.save()`

   - É chamado em um único objeto;
   - Pode ser sobrescrito no modelo para executar lógica própria antes ou depois de salvar de fato;
   - Pode ser usado para criar um novo objeto ou atualizar um objeto já existente. Ele escolhe entre um e outro dependendo do objeto já existir no BD ou não.

     - Para garantir que o Django somente salve se o objeto não existir, passe o argumento `force_insert=True` ao método `save`. Ele lançará uma exceção se o objeto já existir, em vez de fazer um `UPDATE`.
     - Para garantir que o Django somente salve se o objeto existir, passe o argumento `force_update=True` ao método `save`. Ele lançará uma exceção se o objeto não existir, em vez de fazer um `INSERT`.
2. `queryset.update()`

   - É chamado em um *queryset*, podendo afetar zero ou mais objetos simultaneamente;

     - Ele inclusive é chamado *antes* do *queryset* ser avaliado, de modo que ele não faz um `SELECT` e depois um `UPDATE` - ele só faz o `UPDATE`.
   - Não permite executar lógica própria antes ou depois de salvar cada objeto individual. Em particular, ele *não chama* o método `save` de cada objeto atualizado;

     - Se você precisa de alguma lógica customizada durante o salvamento, **não use** o método `update`. Em vez disso salve em um loop:

       ```
       for objeto in queryset:
           objeto.save()
       ```

       Isso é menos eficiente que o método `update` (pois faz N+1 comandos SQL em vez de apenas 1), mas pode ser necessário em algumas situações.
   - Atualiza *todos* os objetos do *queryset* para um único, mesmo valor, em um único comando SQL. Se o valor final puder ser calculado a partir dos valores atuais dos registros, pode-se usar [expressões F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/queries/#f-expressions) junto com esse comando. Exemplo:

     ```
     MeuModelo.objects.filter(campo1=42).update(campo2 = F('campo2') + 1)
     ```

     (Incrementa em 1 a coluna `campo2` de toda linha que possui `campo1` igual a 42, tudo isso num único comando SQL)

Comment: Excelente resposta!

Answer (score 2):

Existem várias diferenças entre os dois.

O `Update` pode ser usado para atualizar vários objetos, o `Save` funciona para salvar uma única linha no banco.

No caso de múltiplas alteração o `Update` vai lhe dar muito mais performasse, porque é uma chamada por queryset.

Em contra partida o `Save` é muito fácil de ser sobre escrito, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
Class myModel(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField()
    date_created = models.DateField()

    def save(self):
        if not self.pk :
           self.date_created = datetime.datetime.now()
        super(myModel , self).save()
```

Não é nada de errado em usar o `Save`, mas caso tenha situações onde você pode fazer alterações em massa pense no uso do `Update`

**ATUALIZAÇAO**

O Save executa qualquer sobre escrita, o Update não vai executar a sobre escrita do metodo Save do model.

[Aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#what-happens-when-you-save) tem um guia legal dizendo o que acontece exatamente no momento de salvar e também fala sobre como ele sabe se é um inclusão ou alteração.

Comment: +1 Note que esses sinais `pre_save` e `post_save` *não são enviados* no caso do `update`, só do `save`.