# Como tornar um campo obrigatório em um model de acordo com uma condição? - Django

Tags: python, django

Eu possuo o seguinte model:

```
class Paciente(models.Model):
usuario = models.ForeignKey(Usuario, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
genero = models.IntegerField(choices=GENERO_PACIENTE_CHOICES)
dt_nasc = models.DateField()
responsavel = models.ForeignKey(PacienteResponsavel, on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True)

@property
def idade(self):
    return int((datetime.now().date() - self.dt_nasc).days / 365.25)
```

Meu objetivo é: quando a idade do paciente for inferior a 18, o campo responsavel deve ser preenchido. Como eu poderia fazer essa validação?

Comment: Acredito que as respostas [desta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101914/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-save-e-update-no-django) podem ajudar a guiá-la para a solução do problema.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode utilizar o método clean() no seu form para verificar a condição:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(NomeDoSeuForm, self).clean()
    field = cleaned_data.get("field")
    field2 = cleaned_data.get("field2")

    if field == "xxx":
        msg = forms.ValidationError("Esse campo é obrigatóio.")
        self.add_error('field2', msg)

    return cleaned_data
```